# How do I configure svcutil-generated code so that it will regenerate the correct WSDL?

Tags: .net, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to generate a .NET SOAP web service (using `svcutil`) from an existing WSDL. The WSDL contains the following information:

```
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<!-- ... -->
<xsd:complexType name="DoStuffType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="..." type="..." />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="DoStuffResponseType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="..." type="..." />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="DoStuff" type="tns:DoStuffType" />
<xsd:element name="DoStuffResponse" type="tns:DoStuffResponseType" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="DoStuffSoapIn">
  <part name="messagePart" element="tns:DoStuff" />
</message>
<message name="DoStuffSoapOut">
  <part name="messagePart" element="tns:DoStuffResponse" />
</message>

<portType name="ASoapService">
  <operation name="DoStuff">
    <input message="tns:DoStuffSoapIn" />
    <output message="tns:DoStuffSoapOut" />
  </operation>
</portType>
```

The generated code compiles and deploys OK but the WSDL that *it* generates does not contain the details of the `DoStuff` operation.

If I remove the `[OperationContract(ReplyAction = "*")]` attribute then I get the following error from the service:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a 
  WSDL export extension: 
System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior 
  contract: http://example.com/services:ASoapService----> 
System.InvalidOperationException: Top level XML element with name
  DoStuffResponse in namespace http://example.com/services cannot reference
  http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Generated:DoStuffResponseType type 
  because it already references a different type 
  (http://example.com/services:DoStuffResponseType). 
Use a different operation name or MessageBodyMemberAttribute to specify a 
  different name for the Message or Message parts.
```

If I then remove the `[MessageContract(IsWrapped="false")]` attribute from the response code I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation 'DoStuff' could not be loaded 
  because it has a parameter or return type of type 
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has 
  MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using 
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, 
  the method must not use any other types of parameters.
```

Additionally removing the `[MessageContract(IsWrapped="false")]` attribute from the request code makes all the errors go away but (not surprisingly perhaps) causes the the request to need wrapping with `<request>` elements.

What do I need to do to the generated code to allow it to regenerate the correct WSDL?

Comment: Look closely at your namespaces. It looks like you are referencing the wrong namespaces.

Comment: That's certainly what the first error suggests but I can't see anything wrong in the code. There are no explicit references to `http://schemas.datacontract.org`. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562927/395718) the solution is to remove `ReplyAction = "*"` part, but keep `OperationContract` attribute.